# How to connect to SQL Server from another computer?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

I want to connect from home using SQL Server 2005 to another PC.

I had a look on the msd...but before connecting it says I should connect to another computer
using the computer management and it didn't work out....I can only connect to computers from my workgroup?

Thanks,
Luisa

Comment: This question is not clear - can you explain what exactly are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to connect to SQL server remotly you need to use a software - like Sql Server Management studio.

The computers doesn't need to be on the same network - but they must be able to connect each other using a communication protocol like tcp/ip, and the server must be set up to support incoming connection of the type you choose.

if you want to connect to another computer (to browse files ?) you use other tools, and not sql server (you can map a drive and access it through there ect...)

To Enable SQL connection using tcp/ip read this article:

For Sql Express: [express](http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/28/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/)
For Sql 2008: [2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191294.aspx)

Make sure you enable access through the machine firewall as well.

You might need to install either SSMS or Toad on the machine your using to connect to the server. both you can download from their's company web site.

Comment: Yes I want to connect remotly...I have access tot the computer using run->mstsc. I set on sql configuration manager protocol tcp/ip as enabled but how I do "the server must be set up to support incoming connection of the type you choose."

Thanks

Comment: mstsc = Microsoft Terminal Services - that has **nothing** to do with SQL Server......

Comment: you are mixing 2 issues:
when you use mstsc - you are actually on the remote machine. you don't need tcp/ip cause you can admin it locally.
I'll edit the answer with info how to enable remote access to sql server

Comment: Check also that SQL Server Browser service is running. That fixed my problem too.

Comment: Articles are useless.

Answer (score 31):

**Disclamer**
This is just some additional information that might help anyone. I want to make it abundantly clear that what I am describing here is possibly:

- A. not 100% correct and
- B. not safe in terms of network security.

I am not a DBA, but every time I find myself setting up a SQL Server (Express or Full) for testing or what not I run into the connectivity issue. The solution I am describing is more for the person who is just trying to get their job done - consult someone who is knowledgeable in this field when setting up a production server. 

**For SQL Server 2008 R2 this is what I end up doing:**

1. Make sure everything is squared away like in this
   [tutorial](http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/28/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/) which is the same tutorial posted above as a solution by "Dani" as the selected answer to this question.
2. Check and/or set, your firewall settings for the computer that is hosting the SQL Server. If you are using a Windows Server 2008 R2 then use the Server Manager, go to Configuration and then look at "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security". If you are using Windows 7 then go to Control Panel and search for "Firewall" click on "Allow a program through Windows Firewall".

   - Create an inbound rule for port TCP 1433 - allow the connection
   - Create an outbound rule for port TCP 1433 - allow the connection
3. When you are finished with the firewall settings you are going to want to check one more thing. Open up the "SQL Server Configuration Manager" locate: SQL Server Network Configuration - Protocols for SQLEXPRESS (or equivalent) - TCP/IP

   - Double click on TCP/IP
   - Click on the IP Addresses tab
   - Under IP1 set the TCP Port to 1433 if it hasn't been already
   - Under IP All set the TCP Port to 1433 if it hasn't been already
4. Restart SQL Server and SQL Browser (do both just to be on the safe side)

Usually after I do what I mentioned above I don't have a problem anymore. Here is a screenshot of what to look for - for that last step:

[image: Port 1433 is the default port used by SQL Server but for some reason doesn't show up in the configuration by default.]

Again, if someone with more information about this topic sees a red flag please correct me.

Comment: You should not explicitly need to set port 1433 in SQL server Configuration Manager. You do however, need to set all the IP Addresses' "Enabled" properties to Yes.

Answer (score 3):

I'll edit my previous answer based on further info supplied. You can clearely ping the remote computer as you can use terminal services.

I've a feeling that port 1433 is being blocked by a firewall, hence your trouble. See [TCP Ports Needed for Communication to SQL Server Through a Firewall](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932) by Microsoft.

Try using [this](http://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php) application to ping your servers ip address and port 1433.

```
tcping your.server.ip.address 1433
```

And see if you get a "Port is open" response from tcping.

Ok, next to try is to check SQL Server. RDP onto the SQL Server computer. Start SSMS. Connect to the database. In object explorer (usually docked on the left) right click on the server and click properties.

[alt text http://www.hicrest.net/server_prop_menu.jpg](http://www.hicrest.net/server_prop_menu.jpg)

Goto the Connections settings and make sure "Allow remote connections to this server" is ticket.

[alt text http://www.hicrest.net/server_properties.jpg](http://www.hicrest.net/server_properties.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

all of above answers would help you but you have to add three ports in the firewall of PC on which SQL Server is installed.

1. Add new TCP Local port in Windows firewall at port no. 1434
2. Add new program for SQL Server and select sql server.exe
       Path: C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft SQL 
   Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe
3. Add new program for SQL Browser and select sqlbrowser.exe
       Path: C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\sqlbrowser.exe

Comment: Thanks a lot man, these last 3 steps finally get it working, well done.