# how to connect to sql server 2008 (R2) on same workgroup on intranet

Tags: sql-server, connection, workgroup

I am trying to connect to sql server R2 instance on same workgroup but I get 
(error: 26 - Error locating server/instance specified).

please Assume I have pc pc1 and pc2 with windows 7 
network connection pc1 - router - pc2
pc2 has my SQL SERVER 2008 R2 instance

I already followed this link
[How to connect to SQL Server from another computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486610/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-from-another-computer)

I did

- allow remote connection on pc2
- enable tcp/ip and set up 1433 port as per "dyslexicanaboko" suggested
  at above link
- created inbound and outbound rules on pc2 for port 1433 to allow
  connection
- i could successfully ping pc2's port 1433 from pc1 (using [tcping](http://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php)
  utility)
- i can browse shared folders of pc2 from pc1 (means my workgroup
  setting is fine)

however i still get error.

Am I still missing something? 
Does my pc2 needs to be logged in as administrator only in order for pc1 to connect? Or
Can a non admin user work on pc2 and I can still connect using pc1?

please be specific... thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is this a named instance?  If so, you need to ensure port 1434 (the default port for SQL Server Browser) is open and listening.

Also, if it is a named instance, you need to ensure that you have the SQL Server Browser service started.  You can do this through the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning off windows firewall in your server box altogether?

I find windows 7 firewall UI pretty confusing compared to XP, sometimes I have more luck just turning it off altogether and attempting a connection to check if that is where the problem is.

In fact, try turning it off on both pc1 and pc2 machines.

[image: Turning off windows firewall]

Answer (score 0):

well somehow following thing worked without making any other changes after all bulleted list in my question is true

in sql management studio use

- server name: (IP address of pc2) works , no need to have parenthesis

  ### OR
- server name: (COMPUTERNAME of pc2) works , no need to have parenthesis

### BOTH OF THESE DO NOT WORK

- (IPaddress of pc2)/(name of sql server instance)
- (COMPUTERNAME of pc2)/(name of sql instance)

### other answers

Does my pc2 needs to be logged in as administrator only in order for pc1 to connect?
**NO**

Or Can a non admin user work on pc2 and I can still connect using pc1? **YES**

*pc2 can be be simply turned on without anybody logged in provided the SQL SERVER service is turned on*