# Invalid Key for attachdbfilename

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using SQL Server DB.  The connection string is

```
Data Source=office1\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\dbSQLTest.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

On local computer it is fine.  On the network computer, it gives
"Invalid Key for attachdbfilename"

I do not want to make server client application. My purpose to use Sql server DB is to run my application on 3-4 computer simultaneously.  I just make shortcut from my main computer to the network computers.
The reason why I donot attach with server instance is that it is difficult for the users to attach DBs with server and then manage SSMS.
Please advise
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AttachDbFilename` is used with local database. If you have remote database then the connection string will [be different](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008). Have a look at article - [How to configure SQL Server 2005 to allow remote connections.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I am understanding you correctly, but you can't simultaneously attach the same MDF on a network drive by several concurrent users (like you can do with MS Access).

Rather just install SQL Express on a central computer and open it up for remote [TCIP/IP access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486610/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-from-another-computer), and change the connection string to an IP / instance one.