# Have a centralized SQL Database

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, networking, database-connection, connection-string

although there may be several duplicates similar to this, but none of them solves my issue.

I have a windows application, which is currently working fine with SQL Express 2008 in Visual Studio 2010. It has one database file.

I want that the applications database should reside on one of the computers in a network, and rest of the networked computers should interact with the central database, I have installed SQL Server 2008 on one of the computers on the network. What more I have to do? I am tored of trying..

Comment: Not a constructive question, everything should work and what you've described is a typical client-server model.

Comment: The problem is that I am not able to connect a **client** to the server, may be I don't know about the connection strings much. I have attached the database on the server, but don't know how to proceed. I have tried attaching database from clients but its saying file is in use.

Comment: You might edit this question to show your existing connection string, the server name of your SQL server, and ask what you need to change to make it work. Chances are, just by putting together the information you'll answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server may require some configuration on server and/or client to get network connections going.

See this other question on this site for a good discussion of the things that may need doing: [How to connect to SQL Server from another computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486610/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-from-another-computer)

Comment: Yes i needed some configuration, and this led to a ban on my account. I created a guest account login on sql server, and it all worked.