# can't establish connection between PHP and SQL Server (Unix)

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm trying to establish a connection between php and SQL Server. Here's the connection function I'm using :

```
$con = new PDO ("dblib:host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1433;dbname=xxxx", $dbuser, $dbpwd);
```

I get the following message : SQLSTATE[28000] Login incorrect. (severity 9)

After having installed freetds-devel, the error has gone but I got an other one : 
SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)

**N.B.:** MSSQL isn't on a UNIX system, but the PHP is.

**SOLUTION:** I changed the TDS version in the FreeTDS.conf (under [global]) to 7.0 and it worked like a charm

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try removing the port `:1433` and/or use `new PDO("mysql:host=...`

Comment: I'm not a php developer, but MS SQL connection strings will have a `key=value` format.  I think you need something like `UID=$dbuser;PWD=$dbpwd`.

Comment: Try `$mysql_hostname = 'xxx'; $mysql_username = 'xxx'; $mysql_password = 'xxx'; $mysql_dbname = 'xxx';` `$con= new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);`

Comment: @Fred-ii-  I did remove the port but I got this error message : SQLSTATE[HY000] Server is unavailable or does not exist. (severity 9)
And I'm not using MySQL but MS SQL

Comment: Then can you try my second suggestion and replace `mysql` with `dblib` @user3375869

Comment: @DMason I did but I still have the same error

Comment: Still not working @Fred-ii-

Comment: Have a look at [**this page**](http://www.jordansphere.co.uk/login-incorrect-when-connecting-from-freebsd-to-sql-server-2008-via-freetds/) and look near the bottom where the person mentions a fix. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm confused though. How can you use an MS SQL on Unix?

Comment: Apparently, it's possible using ODBC and freetds

Comment: @Fred-ii- He's not running MSSQL on the Unix system, hence the `host=ip address` syntax.

Comment: [`See OP's comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253649/cant-establish-connection-between-php-and-sql-server-unix#comment33798648_22253649) @Dan and in the title (UNIX) which is why I'm confused.

Comment: MSSQL isn't on a unix system, but the php is.

Comment: Ah ok; got it. @user3375869 So you're trying to access the server from outside then.

Comment: Ok, well that is something I don't have any experience with. I did find many results in Google that could help, after using "how to access mssql from another server" as the search criteria and found [**this page on SO**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2486610/) yet I suggest you further your research with what I used as a search query. I wish I could have been of more help, good luck; I wish you well, cheers. @user3375869

Comment: Thank you very much @Fred-ii- I wish you luck too

Answer (score -1):

Your username or password are probably incorrect.

Check you have permissions to login from the IP address you're connecting from.