# Connect to SQL Server from Linux, PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, linux

I'm trying to connect to a **SQL Server 2008** from a `Linux`,`PHP` **(cPanel, Greengeeks.com)**.

Server admin says that he added the `Linux` server `IP` to Firewall and enabled `TCP/IP` connection, port is `1433`.

But I still can't connect tot he server.

The Error message is:

> SQLSTATE[01002] (null) (severity 9)

Connection script is:

```
 <?php
  try {
    $hostname = "999.999.255.239\INSTANCENAME";
    $port = '1433';    
    $dbname = "database";
    $username = "user";
    $pw = "pass";
    $dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname;","$username","$pw");
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
  }
```

Please help

Comment: Have you installed the mssql driver for php on you Linux OS?

Comment: @Nurzhan yes I think I did, please take a look at the screenshot of my cPanel PHP Settings http://prntscr.com/czx7f3

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895605/php-pdo-mssql-sqlstate01002-adaptive-server-connection-failed-severity-9

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can `var_dump( $dbh->errorCode() . ' ' . $dbh->errorInfo());` to help you knowing what's wrong with your connection. You know that is necessary to check error with your important steps.